# Hide selenium webdriver window before initializing

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to hide selenium window mean to start chrome window without interupting and in the task bar silently, I don't want headless because it is easily caughted

Note: It must be using some `Options` command because the driver must not be **initialized**

Comment: Why do you want to hide selenium ;)

Comment: Because it minimize window each time, I am playing game with it